# How to read from subset of channels?

Tags: go

There are N channels.

Every receiver wants to get the next message from one of the subsets of the channels.

Need not to loose the messages and keep the messages order by the time.

Here is an example.

We have two channels C1 and C2.

There is a new message in the C2 channel. No receivers. Waiting.

The first receiver wants to read messages from C1 only. No messages in C1. Waiting.

A new message appears in the C1. The first receiver gets this message.

There is a new message in the C1 channel. No receivers. We have messages in C1 and C2 channels.

The second receiver wants to read messages from C1 and C2. The following is very important. The second receiver should get the message exactly from C2 (not a random from C1 or C2) because the message in the C2 channel appeared earlier!

Do you have any ideas on how to implement this using Go channels?

In a real task I have a fixed number of channels (or producers) and calls from the clients with a random subset of channels from which the client wants to get the next message. Like this:

```
type MyChannels map[string] chan int

func NextMessage(wantChannels []string) int {
...
}
```

NextMessage function is a blocking function.

Comment: If you need absolute ordering, you need to add that to the payload itself. You cannot know which channel was ready to recv first (and "first" doesn't even make sense if the sources are not coordinated in any way).

Comment: I am ok to have a payload in the message (not just `int`). Could you please explain your idea in details?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem enough here to propose a solution. It sounds like you need a message broker of some sort in order to enforce ordering. The message may be orderable by payload alone, or the broken may maintain the order for you, but I think you're going to need some sort of metadata to either track where the message is destined, and/or when it arrived.

Comment: Here's the problem with "arrived before" relationships regarding channels: a write operation to a channel blocks until someone reads from it, and until you write, you don't know if it is going to block. So if you are faced with multiple channels are waiting to be read from, you don't know which order they arrived, because if you did, you would've read them already. You can probably do this with an additional shared struct keeping the channel ordering that should be read.

Comment: When you want a straight order, why do you have two channels at all? I'd use one channel and process (and delegate) the messages in the order they get sent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use reflect for selecting from dynamic size channel. For full source code, you may check on [my github](https://github.com/fahimbagar/dynamic-channel). Here is the snapshot

```
func NextMessage(wantChannels []string) int64 {
    // create select array with dynamic size
    cases := make([]reflect.SelectCase, len(wantChannels) + 1)

    // insert default value so it can be waiting
    cases[0] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectDefault}

    for i, wantChan := range wantChannels {
        fmt.Printf("want from Chan %s\n", wantChan)
        cases[i+1] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(myChan[wantChan])}
    }

    for {
        index, value, _ := reflect.Select(cases)
        if index == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%+v waiting for 2 seconds before checking again\n", wantChannels)
            <-time.After(2 * time.Second)
        } else {
            return value.Int()
        }
    }
}
```